# Get steps of numbers between numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I’d like an array of 26 numbers starting at `1` and ending at `42`.

I haven’t been able to find out how to do this (answers seem to be for finding all integers between two numbers vs. a specified number of steps). The numbers can be floats.

Ideally I’d want this as a reusable function, something like:

```
numberRange(lower, upper, steps)
```

As a simple example if I did:

```
numberRange(2, 10, 5)
```

It would return: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved!

```
function getRange(upper, lower, steps) {
  const difference = upper - lower
  const increment = difference / (steps - 1)
  return [lower, ...Array(steps - 2).fill('').map((_, index) => 
    lower + (increment * (index + 1))
  ), upper]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure just division would work:

```
function numberRange(upper, lower, steps) {
    return new Array(steps + 1).fill(undefined).map((v, idx) => (upper / steps) * (idx + 1));
}
```

Comment: If I do `numberRange(10, 2, 5)` it gives me back 6 numbers: `[1.6, 3.2, 4.8, 6.4, 8, 9.6]`. Taking away `steps + 1` fixes that, however I’d like the numbers to start on 2 and end on 10.

Comment: Ok @gosseti I had a typo, fixed it - does it work for you now?

Comment: No luck with that. I still get back one too many numbers and the range starts and ends a bit too high.